# Consistent system bug while using UI test monkey app

Tags: android

I'm using the UI test monkey tool provided with android. This is a consistent error I see and wonder how I can avoid it.

Somehow the test app will rotate the orientation of my app such that the emulator window is still in portrait orientation, but the screen surface is in a landscape orientation. When in this configuration, any time you click on an EditText, a system exception gets thrown:

> "The application OpenWnn (process jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

so this OpenWnn process is not mine, it looks like it handles display of the virtual keyboard. When in this odd orientation mode, and you try to click in an EditText, I can see the virtual keyboard try to slide in from the left side of the screen, then that exception gets thrown.

I'm not sure what orientation this is, because it's not the normal landscape orientation you get by hitting ctrl + F11. In fact, the virtual keyboard shouldn't even be trying to display itself in landscape mode? Much less from the left side of the emulator? Anyone else experience this?

ThanksC

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this a common problem, seems to have been fixed by using a try-catch:

[Google groups answer](http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86/browse_thread/thread/5af3d77513c78c10)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a testing across a pile of Android devices at the moment and this rings a bell - I think this might be a scenario where the device has a physical slide and Monkey is triggering it being opened while the device is in one orientation or another..

I'd suggest you could try your app on a SE Xperia Play with its slide open/closed in each actual orientation, and see if that generates the 'odd orientation mode'/crash you mentioned.. (we had some weird orientation issues with that device, I imagine other devices with physical keyboards may well be the same)